# How to redirect a page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
angular.module('myApp',[])

.controller('loginCtrl',function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location, $window{
$scope.login = function(loginData){

 $scope.dataLoading = true;
 $scope.loginData = angular.copy(loginData);    
 $http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : 'php/login.php',
    params: {'email' : loginData.email,'password': loginData.password,'rand' : Math.random()}
    }).then(function mySucces(response,$location){
      $scope.dataLoading = false;
        $scope.msg1 = response.data.msg1;
        $scope.msg2 = response.data.msg2;
        $scope.firstname = response.data.firstname;
        $scope.flag = response.data.flag;
        console.log($scope.flag);
        $location.url('http://localhost/timetrake/welcome.html');

    }, function myError(response) {

    $scope.user = response.statusText;

    }); 
}   
});
```

Comment: it give error like this  Reference Error: $location is not defined
    at my Succes

Comment: $location needs to be passed as argument in the controller function such as .controller("LocationController", function($scope, $location) {

Comment: what happen when you try to redirect?

Comment: i passed the argument in the controller but it doesn't work

Comment: thank you guys it's working

Comment: @Bhautik129 Don't forget to Mark one of the answers correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Angular $window:

```
$window.location.href = 'timetrake/welcome.html';
```

Then

```
 $scope.dataLoading = true;
 $scope.loginData = angular.copy(loginData);    
 $http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : 'php/login.php',
    params: {'email' : loginData.email,'password': loginData.password,'rand' : Math.random()}
    }).then(function mySucces(response,$location){
      $scope.dataLoading = false;
        $scope.msg1 = response.data.msg1;
        $scope.msg2 = response.data.msg2;
        $scope.firstname = response.data.firstname;
        $scope.flag = response.data.flag;
        console.log($scope.flag);
        $window.location.href = 'timetrake/welcome.html';);

    }, function myError(response) {

    $scope.user = response.statusText;

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$location.path('/timetrake/welcome.html');
```

Why dont you add welcome.html into a scope route config and so u can do '/timetrake/welcome'

Answer (score 0):

Inject `$location` in your controller

For example

```
jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $location){

    $location.url(".....")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $location.path('/timetrake/welcome.html');
```

I prefer you to use `ng-route` it gives you more flexibility and it maintain state for redirection and it can easily navigate by just

```
$state.go()
```